# Navbar elements appear different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Navbar elements appear different in Firefox and Chrome. I use `span` tag to animate hamburger menu but it looks totally different in Firefox. It looks fine in Chrome and other browsers including Android. I tried browser reset CSS also. I don't know what I'm missing.

[image: comparison of firefox and chrome. menu offset in firefox]

> [see this ***jsfiddle*** example in firefox](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshwar018/dt17u5uz/)

```css
html, body, div, span, h1, p, a, address, img, i, ul, li, footer, header, nav, section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
footer, header, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/*----- reset end-----------*/
.header {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .8s;
}
.header nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: sticky;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 16px;
}
.header nav .btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  margin: 16px;
}
.header nav .btn span {
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 95%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transition: background-color .5s .3s;
}
.header nav .btn span:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  display: block;
  top: -0.625rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s .4s,transform .3s;
}
.header nav .btn span:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s .4s,transform .3s;
  top: 0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header" class="header sidbar">

        <nav>
            <button class="btn"><span></span></button>

        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- /header -->


</body>
```

Comment: Please provide also your HTML code

Comment: Is there a reason you've included  SCSS instead of CSS?

Comment: @FluffyKitten no purticular reason. i writen in scss so i pasted it .

Comment: I was wondering because another user here once was including the SCSS in their page instead of the CSS (they had some plugin in their Firefox that interpreted the SCSS directly) - as I was wondering if this was a similar case & the SCSS wasn't interpreted correctly :) Now that you've including the CSS, this helps because now we can actually try it for ourselves. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `top:50%` in your CSS for the `span`. Its not doing anything on Chrome, but in FF its making the span move down 50% further than its default position (which is actually the middle already because you are using a `button`).

You just need to change this class:

```
.header nav .btn span {
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 95%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  /* top: 50%;  <- remove this and it works!  */
  transition: background-color .5s .3s;
}
```

If you used a div instead of a button you'd need to account for placing the span in the center, but the `button` element it is automatically centering the content vertically. By specifying that you want the top at 50%, FF is adding the 50% on to the current centred position.

**Working example** when you remove `top`:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dt17u5uz/2/ or Snippet:

```css
html, body, div, span, h1, p, a, address, img, i, ul, li, footer, header, nav, section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
footer, header, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/*----- reset end-----------*/
/* autoprefixer: off */
/* autoprefixer: off */
.header {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .8s;
}
.header nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: sticky;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 16px;
}
.header nav .btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0 16px 16px;
}
.header nav .btn span {
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 95%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  transition: background-color .5s .3s;
}
.header nav .btn span:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  display: block;
  top: -0.625rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s .4s,transform .3s;
}
.header nav .btn span:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #FD5B4E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1875rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s .4s,transform .3s;
  top: 0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header" class="header sidbar">

    <nav>
      <button class="btn"><span></span></button>

    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- /header -->


</body>
```

FYI, you also have collapsing margin problems on your button, this might just be because you are only showing us part of your code. One way to overcome this is to add `overflow:auto` to your `.header nav {}` CSS rule. More about [collapsing margins from sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/)

Comment: thanks bro it really helped me to understand button and div. I'm using Css grid. Will that affect margin collapse in FF?. WHAT should I do for that fix?

Comment: @Vigneshwarkumar FYI, here's the fiddle updated with `overflow:auto` added: https://jsfiddle.net/dt17u5uz/3/ Compare it to https://jsfiddle.net/dt17u5uz/2/ and you'll see the difference that the collapsing margin was causing.